# Good Password generation

Tags: passwords, password-encryption

I am new to the coding scene. I was wondering about something. So I see a lot of password generators make passwords that are crazy long and complication. But this issue here is the password can be hard to remember of course. So this is my solution I created a long password that is easy to remember to myself. Each letter is pretty memorization to a point in my life.
kaliofh;sofj;eubahxljmufos8mrp3p7n409vuno8cm
it looks like random but its not random instead it actually means something to me lol.

Anyways. Im' wondering if something like this would be a good password. Because All though I won't forget it. I can imagine somebody would. Also how can I make this pw better?

Thanks everyone I look forward to coding.

I have tried to make multiple passwords before. This is the password I would like to become personal.

Comment: for context. the first few letters are:
k - kelsey (my mother name)

Comment: a -> abigale my daughter name

Comment: l -> lion her favored animals

Comment: no more so I dont spoil.!

Answer (score 0):

This would be impossible. Unless you have a dictionary with every letter with a value of that letter like this:

```
my_dict = {
"a": "Abigail"
 etc...
```

Then randomly chose a key from it, technically you could, but if you wanted a secure password like `secrets.token_hex(20)`, it would be impossible.